# Executing multiple items from a list against same subprocess

Tags: python

One more question on this as I cant find the answer elsewhere regarding this list.

I have the following line of code

```
process = subprocess.Popen(GBTest + ' --record '+ DEVICES[0] + ' ' + APP + ' ' + EMAIL, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

DEVICES[] - has multiple items stored in it and I can call each one individually with Devices[0] or Devices[1] etc... is there a way to modify this string so that it will run this line of code for each Device in that list?

If not what will I need to add?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want a loop?

Comment: Just use a loop.

Comment: Tried exactly this as listed below and it isnt looping

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
for x in DEVICES:
    process = subprocess.Popen(GBTest + ' --record '+ x + ' ' + APP + ' ' + EMAIL, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Ya thats what I thought too but it is only executing it one time

Comment: To specify further it is recording for what would be Device[1] and not for Device[0]

Comment: Then your array contains only one element or the command you're executing doesn't execute for that element. Try subprocess.check_output()

Answer (score 0):

I got it, needed to add in a sleep(time) to have it run each device sequentially. Think it was a limitation of the software I am hooking into.

Thanks